# PySpark structured streaming output sink as Kafka giving error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Using Kafka 0.9.0 and Spark 2.1.0 - I am using PySpark structured streaming to compute the results and output it on Kafka topic. I am referring the Spark docs for the same 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes

Now when I run the command

(output mode complete as it is aggregating the streaming data.)

```py
(mydataframe.writeStream
    .outputMode("complete")
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "x.x.x.x:9092")
    .option("topic", "topicname")
    .option("checkpointLocation","/data/checkpoint/1")
    .start())
```

It gives me error as below

```
 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = 0686130b-8668-48fa-bdb7-b79b63d82680, runId = b4b7494f-d8b8-416e-ae49-ad8498dfe8f2] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'value' not found;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:73)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.validateQuery(KafkaWriter.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.write(KafkaWriter.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSink.addBatch(KafkaSink.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:502)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:177)**
```

Not sure what attribute value does it expects. Need help in resolving this.

The console output sink produces the correct output on console so code seems to work fine. Only when using kafka as output sink causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure what attribute value does it expects. Need help in resolving this.

Your `myDataFrame` needs a column `value` (of either `StringType` or `BinaryType`) containing the payload (message) which you want to send to Kafka.

Currently you are trying to write to Kafka, but don't describe which data is to be written.

One way to obtain such a colunm is to rename an existing column using `.withColumnRenamed`. If you want to write multiple columns, it's usually a good idea to create a column containing a JSON representation of the dataframe, which can be obtained using the `to_json` sql.function. [But beware of .toJSON!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614364/sparks-dataset-tojson-is-not-structuredstreaming-compatible-how-to-convert-a-d)

Answer (score 0):

Spark 2.1.0 does not support Kafka as output sink. It's been introduced in 2.2.0 as per [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996293/how-to-write-streaming-dataset-to-kafka/42996602#42996602), which links to the commit introducing the feature, and provides an alternate solution, as well as this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21267), which added the documentation in 2.2.1.

Comment: That is just a follow up error from your original issue though, the error message you mentioned will only be cured by using the correct nomenclature in the dataframe.